# $\sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_k$ vs $\sum_{k=m}^n u_k (v_k-v_{k-1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Given that for two sequences $(u_k)_k$ and $(v_k)_k$,
$$\sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_k=u_n v_n -u_m v_{m-1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}v_k (u_k-u_{k+1}),$$
why does this equal $\sum_{k=m}^n u_k (v_k-v_{k-1})$ for two sequences  $(u_k)_{k=1}^n$ and $(v_k)_{k=0}^n$?

I think that
$$\sum_{k=m}^n u_k (v_k-v_{k-1})=u_n v_n -u_m v_{m-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_k (u_k-u_{k+1})\color{red}{-u_n v_{n-1}+u_m v_{m-2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_{k-1}(u_k-u_{k+1})},$$
so the equality should be true iff the red expression is equal to $0$, but why should that be the case?

Comment: You have a display equation and ask "why does this equal" a sum of $u \Delta v$.  Is the claim "these three things are equal"?

Comment: The use of $m$ and $n$ in the subscripts on the right-hand side of your last display makes it unclear what distinction you intend to draw.

Comment: @EricTowers The question is, why does $\sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_k$ equal $\sum_{k=m}^n u_k(v_k-v_{k-1})$ in that particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not necessarily equal. Their difference is
$$ \sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_k - \sum_{k=m}^n u_k (v_k - v_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_k - \left(\sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_k - \sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_{k-1}\right) = \sum_{k=m}^n u_k v_{k-1}$$ They are equal iff this difference is $0$. Also note that $v_{m-1}$ does not appear in the original sum so care must be taken when defining those sequences. You might also be interested in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts).